# Serializing complex XML string content

Tags: c#, .net, xml, deserialization

I'm trying to serialize XML content to an object. I'm using .Net 4.6.1. The XML I'm trying to serialize is:

```
<THEROOT>
  <ITEM>
    <TITLE>
      This is my title
    </TITLE>
    <DESCRIPTION>
      <P>Line 1 of the description</P>
      <P>Line 2 of the description</P>
      <P>Final line of description</P>
    </DESCRIPTION>
    <MOREINFO>
      <P>Some additional stuff here</P>
      <P>And another line</P>
      <P>And final line</P>
    </MOREINFO>
  </ITEM>
  <ITEM>
    <TITLE>
      Another object is here
    </TITLE>
    <DESCRIPTION>
      <P>Some description</P>
      <P>That I need to parse</P>
      <P>Into a string</P>
    </DESCRIPTION>
    <MOREINFO>
      <P>More info lines</P>
      <P>Would go here</P>
    </MOREINFO>
  </ITEM>
</THEROOT>
```

And here's the object I'm trying to serialize to:

```
public class TestModel
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "THEROOT")]
    public class TheRoot
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ITEM")]
        public List<Item> Item { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "ITEM")]
    public class Item
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "TITLE")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "DESCRIPTION")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "MOREINFO")]
        public string MoreInfo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And for completeness, this is my serialisation code (assuming the XML content above is a string)..

```
TestModel.TheRoot rootObject;
using (TextReader tr = new StringReader(myXML))
{
    using (XmlTextReader xr = new XmlTextReader(tr))
    {
        xr.Namespaces = false;
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestModel.TheRoot));
        rootObject = (TestModel.TheRoot)serializer.Deserialize(xr);
    }
}
```

In it's current state, I get the error "ReadElementString method can only be called on elements with simple or empty content".  I understand this is because I have html tags in my description content which are deserialized as complex objects.

I've discovered I 'could' modify the model to be like this..

```
public class TestModel
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "THEROOT")]
    public class TheRoot
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ITEM")]
        public List<Item> Item { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "ITEM")]
    public class Item
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "TITLE")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "DESCRIPTION")]
        public Description Description { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "MOREINFO")]
        public MoreInfo MoreInfo { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "DESCRIPTION")]
    public class Description
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "P")]
        public P[] P { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "MOREINFO")]
    public class MoreInfo
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "P")]
        public P[] P { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "P")]
    public class P
    {
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And that does work to some extent - but it's cumbersome when I know I just want to treat the entire content as a string.  **Assuming I cannot change the format of the XML, is there a way I can get both the Description and MoreInfo nodes to each deserialise to a single string object?**

I've seen various posts on here and other sites but none seem to work flawlessly.

Comment: You could always just have a read-only property that returns the content of the `P` items as one string: `public string Content => string.Join(" ", Description.P)`

Comment: I did actually have that, but the problem is I need to serialise it to some kind of structure in the first place.  I'd rather not use the second model shown because it's messy (the actual model is much larger than this).  Agreed though - if there's a way to force the serialiser to put the content into an array of strings or whatever - I could do this alongside another solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my take on this:

Attribute the properties that might contain sub elements (HTML entities) with `XmlIgnore`, like the following:

```
[XmlIgnore, XmlElement(ElementName = "DESCRIPTION")]
```

and

```
[XmlIgnore, XmlElement(ElementName = "MOREINFO")]
```

Then attach a delegate to `UnknownElement` event (`UnknownNode` and `UnknownAttribute` are also available.) on the serializer.

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestModel.TheRoot));
serializer.UnknownElement += Serialize_PossibleHTMLElementToString;
```

With a bit of reflection, you can treat all the inner nodes of the parent element as string (such as HTML you wish to preserve). This method can be modified to make it more case specific.

```
    private static void Serialize_PossibleHTMLElementToString(object sender, XmlElementEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ObjectBeingDeserialized != null)
        {
            var node = e.Element.InnerXml;
            string elementName = e.Element.Name;

            Item item = (Item)e.ObjectBeingDeserialized;

            var element = item.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(XmlElementAttribute), true).Where(attr => (attr as XmlElementAttribute).ElementName == elementName).Count() > 0);

            if(element != null)
                element.SetValue(item, node.Trim());
        }
    }
```

This would produce the following output:

[image]

Comment: Despite the fact I'd already used this approach earlier in testing, I've come full circle back to it.  It's not perfect (an attribute to mark an element and all of it's children as text content would be nice) but combined with custom attribute it does the job and seems the best solution for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this recently and I would like to suggest using XSLT transforms to deal with complex scenarios.

### One of my xslt files for example

XSL allows to pick and choose the data you want to work with and can be quite flexible.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="ClaimDisciplines">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//Providers/ProviderDetail"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//Providers/ProviderDetail">
    <xsl:element name="ClaimDisciplineDTO">
        <xsl:element name="OriginalId">
            <xsl:value-of select="DisciplineID" />
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="DisciplineDescription">
            <xsl:value-of select="DisciplineDescription" />
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="SubDisciplineId">
            <xsl:value-of select="SubDisciplineID"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="DicsiplineGuid">
            <xsl:value-of select="DisciplineGuid" />
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="IsMain">
            <xsl:value-of select="IsMain" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

### The code I use to do the serialization into the necessary object

This code is generic and also makes provision for empty fields in the xml.

```
public static class XmlHelpers
{
    public static T DeserializeXmlObject<T>(string xml) where T : class
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xml))
        {
            return default;
        }

        using (var stringReader = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

            return (T) serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
        }
    }

    public static List<T> PopulateDtoFromXml<T>(string pathToXsl, string inputXml) where T : class
    {
        var stylesheet = new XslCompiledTransform();
        stylesheet.Load(pathToXsl);


        List<T> returnList = default;

        using (var sr = new StringReader(inputXml))
        {
            using (var xr = XmlReader.Create(sr))
            {
                using (var sw = new StringWriter())
                {
                    stylesheet.Transform(xr, null, sw);
                    var resultXml = sw.ToString();

                    var cleanXml = XDocument.Parse(resultXml, LoadOptions.None);
                    cleanXml.Descendants()
                        .Where(e => e.IsEmpty || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Value))
                        .Remove();

                    var listOfItems = cleanXml.Descendants().Where(x => x.HasElements && x.Ancestors().Any()).ToList();

                    foreach (var item in listOfItems)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var result = DeserializeXmlObject<T>(item.ToString());

                            if (result == null) continue;
                            if (returnList == null) returnList = new List<T>();
                            returnList.Add(result);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(e);
                            throw;
                        }
                    }


                }
            }
        }


        return returnList;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting - we already extensively use XSLTs for different parts of our application but it's a bit overkill given I just want to get a string content for a handful of items. Transforms are extremely powerful though, but a bit ugly to support.

Answer (score 1):

Use XML LINQ :

```
using System;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication9
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestModel model = new TestModel(FILENAME);
        }
    }
    public class TestModel
    {
        public List<Item> items { get; set; }
        public TestModel(string filename)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename);

            items = doc.Descendants("ITEM").Select(x => new Item()
            {
                Title = ((string)x.Element("TITLE")).Trim(),
                Description = string.Join(",", x.Element("DESCRIPTION")
                   .Elements("P").Select(y => (string)y)),
                MoreInfo = string.Join(",", x.Element("MOREINFO")
                   .Elements("P").Select(y => (string)y))
            }).ToList();
        }


    }
    public class Item
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public string MoreInfo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

Use following with your solution to flatten results

```
            private string _Description { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "DESCRIPTION")]
            public Description Description
            {
                get { return new Description() { P = _Description.Split(new char[] { ',' }).Select(x => new P() { Text = x}).ToArray() }; }
                set
                {
                    _Description = string.Join(",",value.P.Select(x => x.Text));
                }
            }

            private string _MoreInfo { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "MOREINFO")]
            public MoreInfo MoreInfo
            {
                get { return new MoreInfo() { P = _MoreInfo.Split(new char[] { ',' }).Select(x => new P() { Text = x }).ToArray() }; }
                set
                {
                    _MoreInfo = string.Join(",", value.P.Select(x => x.Text));
                }
            }
```

Comment: Should have said, was ideally looking for a solution using XmlSerializer. Appreciate I could do it with dom parsing but we already have something similar for our current solution. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: I added code to flatten results using your serialization.